# Is there a way to lock down a network?

Tags: network, attacks, attack-prevention, ids

If supposing I discover that my network is being attacked by some hacker or is being compromised in any way and I am able to detect it. So, is there any software-oriented way of 'locking-down' the network?

Basically, that means that there would be NO traffic at all in the whole network. A solution like yanking the model cable is not appreciated. Could it be somehow done in a more subtle way? blocking an IP address would not be the best because the person on the other end could spoof it or more certainly, could just get himself assigned another IP address by using other devices.

> Could it be also done in a way as to only block traffic from that specific person so that legitimate traffic is not hindered? Maybe to identify him without something being easily changeable like IP or MAC address?

I have a Mi model 2 router but it doesn't support shutting down traffic or itself (except, I guess a reboot). So I want a solution that could be done from a computer itself with no other hardware...

Comment: Your switch could deny switching any packets

Comment: switch? I am using a router (Mi model 2). Could it be done with that?

Comment: Routers connect two networks to each other. Switches connect hosts inside networks. Most "consumer" routers also have a switch built in.

Comment: @MechMK1 I get it but as said in the updated question, I want a solution that can be done with a computer..

Comment: The best possible thing you can do is just turn off the device.

Comment: @MechMK1 and disable Wake-On-LAN

Comment: Can you define "legitimate traffic"?

Comment: Well, I guess the best I could do is to get a script to press the reboot button on my router. But still.....@HagenvonEitzen all traffic without any malicious intent...

Comment: Yes, VLANs ACLs.

Comment: @Overmind Could you please elaborate? Also, there is a chance that the specific feature might not be in my router.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blocking the whole network is easy: you flood the whole network with high volume packets so that nothing else can communicate.

If you got very clever, you could script something to log into your home router's web interface and shut down the network or reboot it.

**For a targeted approach:**

As a matter of networking, one node cannot block another node. You would need a central control node, like a switch, to block communication from a node to make sure that the node was blocked and you did not also affect all the other nodes.

At the switch level, you can block the port, not the IP or MAC, that is the source of the unwanted traffic. This is a very common approach. This function is not available on home equipment.

Using your home router's web interface, you might be able to figure out the port, and use whatever functions are available on the router to block the node. But that's quite the sophisticated level of browser automation.

Comment: Flooding looks like an option, but if I reboot won't the hacker just come again with the same IP but with a different attack?

Comment: That would be the same problem with any response.

Comment: So what is the correct response? from a home-based level?

Comment: What outcome are you looking for?

Comment: To discourage the person running scripts and make him abandon the whole thing, hopefully :) In my country there are a lot of kids (one of them is my friend) who just runs those Scripted programs on others for fun (They need to get a life). So to just discourage those types of people...

Comment: That's a very, very different problem. Get a router with a guest network, and only give out the wifi password to the guest network. Then none of your own devices are under threat.

Comment: People who are willing to "mess around" are also willing to endure minor inconvenience or just simply wait.

Comment: Ok, will end this for now. See how scripted attacks take 5 minutes :- https://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/hack-wi-fi-networks-more-easily-with-lazy-script-0185764/

Comment: Yes, I know how to break into a wifi network. I've done it lots before. You cannot block those types of attacks.

Comment: Damn :( Wish I could...

Comment: Limit the wireless range to your house. Get multiple APs if the signal won't fit in your walls well enough. Turn on every security feature that makes sense for your setup. Send all traffic through a dedicated firewall with fine grained rules for traffic that is absolutely required on your network. Set up host based firewalls on all devices, and set up a network IDS device and IPS programs on each device.

Comment: If you want, disable features on each device that make them reconnect if disconnected. Then script out a deauth attack for all wireless devices when a specific IDS alert is caught (detecting an intrusion). Potentially also hook up an air raid siren outside the home to discourage any potential wardrivers.

Comment: At the switch level, what you can block depends on the SW type. Some even have L3 functionality and you can make extended access-list practically blocking by any L2/L3 rules you need.